# Oracle APEX Report with Master and Detail Sections

Tags: oracle, report, oracle-apex

I want to create a report in Oracle APEX, which has both master and detail section, where the master section gets displayed repeatedly on every page of the report (like name, address etc), and the detail section gets displayed after the master section. Pretty much like a back statement, the name, address, account number etc are displayed at top on every page of the statement, and the transaction history is displayed afterwards.

I am able to generate an APEX report like this, but the issue I have is the printing. I tried classic and interactive report both, and the print function that comes with APEX report only exports the contents that's returned by the sql. If I create any other page items to store and display such as name, address etc, it won't be displayed on the pdf that's exported by the print function that comes with APEX report.

Like the below example, is there any way to display "Store No: 2102" on every page of the pdf that's exported by the print function that comes with APEX report?[image]